# How to do a where exists in nested query with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a `WHERE EXISTS` clause in SQLAlchemy. The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
    id, title
FROM
    package AS package1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            title
        FROM
            package as package2
        WHERE
            package1.id <> package2.id AND
            package1.title = package2.title
    )
ORDER BY
    title DESC;
```

Is it possible to do this in SQLAlchemy without using raw SQL?  I've tried this but it doesn't seem to be returning the correct results:

```
    t = model.Session.query(
        model.Package.id,
        model.Package.title
    ).subquery('t')

    package = model.Session.query(
        model.Package.title
    ).filter(
        model.Package.id != t.c.id,
        model.Package.title == t.c.title
    )
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [sqlalchemy.orm.aliased()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased) and [exists()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=exists#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

package_alias = aliased(Package)

session.query(Package.id, Package.title) \
       .filter(session.query(package_alias.title) \
                      .filter(Package.id != package_alias.id) \
                      .filter(Package.title == package_alias.title) \
                      .exists()) \
       .order_by(Package.title.desc())
```